# Steam pressure across branched pipes

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Suppose steam is flowing through a pipe where the steam pressure is X Kg/sqcm. It then branches into two identical pipes. So, what would be the steam pressure at the branched pipes? (Let us assume that the pipes are all 10 meters long and no heat loss occurs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the steam really 'flows', one would need the flow rate and the pipes' geometry (as well as other parameters as e.g. the steam temperature) in order to calculate anything. And it would not be a simple calculation.

This is why engineers generally don't calculate such things. They get the "steam pipeline handbook", find the table titled "dynamic steam pressure loss" and look for the particular pipe fittings and lengths.

On the other hand, if the flow rate is zero or near zero, one could simply assume that the pressure is the same in the whole system, accurate to the hydrostatic corrections (if the pipes are not flat down on the ground).

Comment: Thank You for the answer.

Comment: I'll check the Handbook.

Comment: @ArijitMoitra it is better to wait at least for 1 day for more answers and then choose the best one